# Flutter. How to correctly update state of nested widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, statefulwidget, flutter-state, flutter-radiobutton

I'm new in flutter and I'm trying to implement something like radio group with custom buttons in Android. For this I created StatefulWidget, which hold list of selectable buttons. For every button I was set  press listener where I do something like this:

```
  setState(() {
      buttons.forEach((button) => button.isSelected = false);
      buttons[selectedButtonIndex].isSelected = true;
    });
```

And then my `CustomButtonWidget` changes color depending on the parameter `isSelected` .

All this works well. However, I have an additional requirement. I need my `RadioGroupWidget` to return the selected button type. For this I created a callback :

```
 final ValueChanged<ButtonType> onChanged;
```

And now my button press listener looking like this:

```
onTap: () {
      setState(() {
          buttons.forEach((button) => button.isSelected = false);
          buttons[selectedButtonIndex].isSelected = true;
        });
      onChanged(buttons[selectedButtonIndex].type);
}
```

Next I get this type of button in my other widget which is using `RadioGroupWidget`:

```
CustomRadioGroup(
   onChanged: (value) {
       setState(() {
          buttonType= value;
        });
    }),
)
```

As you can see I call again `setState`. This is what leads to the problem. But I need to do this, because I need to update the state of another widget (for example let's call it `InfoWidget`) depending on the selected button.

After all these manipulations, the state of the `InfoWidget` is updated correctly, but the state of the selected button in the `RadioGroupWidget` does not change. I tried to debug this and I see that at first the parameter `isSelected`  is set to true for the desired button, but after the state of the button I selected is not updated, because its parameter `isSelected`  becomes false. And I don't understand why this is happening.

Please help, I am completely confused.

Comment: Have you tried using [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html)

Comment: You somehow need to pass the buttonType value that received in `CustomRadioGroup().onChange()` to the constructor of `CustomRadioGroup` again so that you can identify the value which is selected even after updating the state of the `RadioGroupWidget`.